# Issue with external auth data retrieval using owin

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

can anybody provide an example how to retrieve profile picture url from Facebook? 
Somehow i can't do this. I can retrieve first name, last name, email, gender and it should allow to retrieve profile picture but it doesn`t. There is no such thing as picture in Claim list.
I couldn't find any examples.  Here is my code:

Startup.Auth.cs

```
var x = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions();
x.Scope.Add("email");
//x.Scope.Add("picture");
x.AppId = "*";
x.AppSecret = "***";
x.Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
{
     OnAuthenticated = async context =>
     {
          context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("FacebookAccessToken", context.AccessToken));
          foreach(var claim in context.User)
          {
               var claimType = string.Format("urn:facebook:{0}", claim.Key);
               string claimValue = claim.Value.ToString();
               if(!context.Identity.HasClaim(claimType, claimValue))
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(claimType, claimValue, "XmlSchemaString", "Facebook"));
          }
     }
};

x.SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie;
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(x);
```

Code how i retrieve some data:

```
var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalIdentityAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
var firstNameClaim = loginInfo.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "urn:facebook:first_name");
var lastNameClaim = loginInfo.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "urn:facebook:last_name");
var gender = loginInfo.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "urn:facebook:gender");
```

Any ideas? I achieve needed result with Facebook SDK for .NET but i curious how can i achieve the same result without using Facebook SDK for .NET. Hope community will help on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It`s seems that you can't get picture url as object with parameters because picture URL will change every time users will change his profile picture so storing static url doesn't make any sense.

For my solution i wrote a method for getting dynamic url for profile picture here is the code:

```
private string GetFacebookProfilePicture(ClaimsIdentity externalInfoSoruce) {
        var facebookUserID = externalInfoSoruce.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "urn:facebook:id").Value;
        string profilePicturePath = string.Format("http://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture?type=large", facebookUserID);
        return profilePicturePath;
    }
```

Now everytime i want to show to user his profile picture i can insert that link in to `<img>` src parameter. And photo will be updated automatically everytime user will login.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the way you're supposed to do it. But Facebook profile pics are available at http://graph.facebook.com/FACEBOOKID/picture, so you just need to get the user's ID and swap it into that URL.

For example, my Facebook ID is 729196216, so if you request http://graph.facebook.com/729196216/picture you get my ugly mug. :)

Comment: Yes, i know this one. But you cannot set height or other parameters  as you can do it in Graph Explorer.If you write ther me/picture?redirect=false you`ll get parameters of current users profile picture. There should be some other way to do it.

Comment: Chmm.. it`s seems that this link is working. But is there any chance to retrieve URL or Picture Object within scope Like we are receiving name, last name, email and gender? 
Because in in Facebook SDK you can receive Picture object or only picture URL